# How is an element with xmlns different from one created with createElementNS with the same namespaceURI?

Tags: xml, dom, mime-types, xml-namespaces

Assume we have the following XML:

```xml
<ns:xml xmlns:ns="AAA">
  <predefined xmlns="AAA"/>
</ns:xml>
```

When running the following code in the browser:

```js
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(XML, 'text/xml');

const added = doc.createElementNS('AAA', 'added');
doc.documentElement.appendChild(added);
```

just serializing `added` returns `<added xmlns="AAA"/>`
but when serializing `doc` the result is

```xml
<ns:xml xmlns:ns="AAA">
  <predefined xmlns="AAA"/>
  <a:added />
</ns:xml>
```

Why are `predefined` and `added` behaving differently?
or asked the other way around:
How would I be able to create an element like `predefined` using `createElementNS` (and other DOM APIs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `added` behave like `predefined`  you need to explicitly set the `xmlns` attribute to the same namespace as the `namespaceURI` argument:

```js
const added = doc.createElementNS('AAA', 'added');
added.setAttribute('xmlns', 'AAA');
doc.documentElement.appendChild(added);
```

Also be aware that parsing it with the mime type `text/html` changes the behavior of (parsing and) serialization to result in the following:

```xml
<ns:xml xmlns:ns="AAA">
  <predefined xmlns="AAA"></predefined>
  <added xmlns="AAA"></added>
</ns:xml>
```